# Serialize RestHighLevelClient from 'org.elasticsearch.client'

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I want to serialize RestHighLevelClient from elastic. Below is my code

```
 import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient
 @Component
 public class Client implements Serializable {
  private transient RestHighLevelClient client;
  @PostContruct
  private void init() {
  //code to initialize RestHighLevelClient 
  }
}
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws Exception {
 oos.defaultWriteObject();
 oos.writeObject(client); 
}
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws Exception 
{ 
  ois.defaultReadObject(); 
  client= (RestHighLevelClient)ois.readObject(); 
}
```

I have written readObject and writeObject to serialize.But it is not working as expected. Any clue on how to serialize it?

Comment: there is no suggestion ?